# Fail to launch SemanticMapEditor

Tags: knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am using Ubuntu 12.04 with ROS Fuerte. Recently, I tried to start SemanticMapEditor but it fails.

Error messages are listed below: (ROS master already started)

```
rosfuerte@rosfuerte-K53SM:~/project/ros/my_package/mod_semantic_map/bin$ ./SemanticMapEditor 
lights() is not available with this renderer.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at processing.core.PApplet.runSketch(Unknown Source)
    at processing.core.PApplet.main(Unknown Source)
    at edu.tum.cs.ias.knowrob.map.SemanticMapEditor.main(SemanticMapEditor.java:69)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at controlP5.ControlWindow.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at controlP5.ControlP5.init(Unknown Source)
    at controlP5.ControlP5.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at de.tum.in.fipm.kipm.gui.visualisation.base.PrologVisualizationCanvas.initControlP5(PrologVisualizationCanvas.java:431)
    at de.tum.in.fipm.kipm.gui.visualisation.base.PrologVisualizationCanvas.<init>(PrologVisualizationCanvas.java:70)
    at edu.tum.cs.ias.knowrob.map.SemanticMapEditor.<init>(SemanticMapEditor.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:374)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)
    ... 3 more
```

I had this line in my /.bashrc:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java export JAVA_HOME PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin export PATH
```

How to solve this problem?

Thanks~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/74329/fail-to-launch-semanticmapeditor/) by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1371 on 2013-08-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems that you are still using the old version in the mod_semantic_map package. It's recommended that you switch to the new one as described here http://www.knowrob.org/doc/semantic_map_editor

If you still use the old KnowRob version, please also update to the new source version hosted at github by following the instructions here http://www.knowrob.org/installation#installation_from_source

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2013-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on 2013-08-22**:
Cool! Thanks~I'll try later!